# Sass mixin color palette between two colors

Tags: colors, sass

I need to create a mixin in Sass that has 3 parameters($startingColor, $endingColor, and $n- number of blocks to create). It has to be tonal transition (color palette) between these two colors. Can anyone help me?:)

Comment: Please share a code sample of what you have tried so far

Answer (score 4):

Well okay, I favorited this question half an hour ago but then I realised the mix() function of sass. After a little brainstorm, its here for you;

```
@mixin tonal-transition($x, $y, $c){
  @for $i from 1 through $c {
    > * {
      &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
        background: mix($y, $x, 100% * $i/$c);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And [here is codepen](https://codepen.io/egemenu/pen/OjMmdz).